# How to host multiple IIS docker containers with Asp.Net based websites on the same VM host

Tags: asp.net, azure, docker, iis

With IIS you can host multiple websites using Port 80 and point them to different domains, IIS handles the mapping for you.

Now with Docker containers using this image:

docker pull microsoft/aspnet

Image contains:

```
Windows Server Core as the base OS
IIS 10 as Web Server
.NET Framework (multiple versions available)
.NET Extensibility for IIS
```

How do you host multiple containers with this image as containers are trying to use the Port 80.

But, currently containers really can't share the same port, must have different listening ports.

So how do one host multiple containers using this image with multiple websites and map them to different domains?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind more than one IIS on the `port 80` if you give one IP address to each of them.

Instead of exposing the `port 80` directly you can specify which is the IP assigned to each container:

```
$ docker run --rm --name iis1 -p 10.0.0.101:80:80 <image>

$ docker run --rm --name iis2 -p 10.0.0.102:80:80 <image>
```